# Мне нужно бесплатное API как Google Place Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Мне нужно API с помощью которого можно реализовать поле с autocomplete для поиска города. Т.е. нужно готовое поле поиска в котором при вводе символов наименования города происходит автопобор подходящих значений в выпадающем списке. Обязательно без карты на js или React. Очень сильно подходит Google Place Autocomplete. Но там платно. Может кто знает еще подобный сервис как у гугл, только бесплатно?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=881&sxsrf=ALeKk01EOh6KWQJYQpZ3eK9QDc58TOqPTw%3A1615100729501&ei=OXtEYP6WHsyxkwWKiqqIAw&q=free+alternative+Google+Place+Autocomplete&oq=free+alternative+Google+Place+Autocomplete&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BAgjECc6BggAEAgQHlChDljfIWDmI2gAcAJ4AIABrQGIAZoHkgEDMC42mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi-l4iKz53vAhXM2KQKHQqFCjEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5 вот список алтернатив, на счет бесплатности не знаю посмотри в каждом. вот еше схожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401419/alternative-to-google-places-autocomplete

Comment: Пытаться https://geoawesomeness.com/google-maps-api-alternatives-best-cheap-affordable/ и https://github.com/pelias/documentation/ и https://pelias.io/

Comment: Спасибо! Я еще нашла хороший вариант: react-mapbox-autocomplete

Comment: Отличная работа! Вы также можете написать это как ответ на свой вопрос после нескольких дней попытки [react-mapbox-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapbox-autocomplete).